# Command line interface for python

Tags: python, linux, windows

I want to create a program by python, when the program is run, it show its own command line interface. The user can input a command into the interface, and the program will handle that command. Is there any way to do that in **both Windows and Linux environment**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work for both linux and windows:

```
from subprocess import call

while True:
    print call(raw_input("command: "), shell = True)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I know raw_input() function does not work in windows

Comment: @Waveter it works, but only for python 2.x, if you have python 3.x you should use `str(input("command: "))`